# How to get currently entering text in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i am developing a project. On that i need to get currently typing characters in a particular column of JTable. 
If i am using,

```
 table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 1)
```

it will return nothing till i select another column. How can i get currently entering text in JTable?

Comment: You mean you want to get what the user is currently typing within the active editable cell?  Okay, why?

Comment: yeah you are correct. Because i want it for some operation. thats why.

Comment: Why can't you wait till the operation is complete and the value is sent to the models `setValueAt` method?

Comment: i wanna use the corrently entering text with Like query. so it will check with my database and return related values to JList. from that i may select and set value in the corresponding cell. Can you understand my problem? if user enters "a" means it will return "apple, ant" like this to jlist.

Comment: So you want to a type of "autocomplete"/"lookup" while the user is typing?  Change the cell editor to one that provides the functionality you want.  Have a look at [JTable, Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jcombobox with autocomplete decorator in a JTable column,here is how [Using a Combo Box as an Editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). and on key typed set the [DefaultComboBoxModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html)
with the JList

Answer (score 0):

You can get the editor being used by calling the method:

```
Component component = table.getEditorComponent();
```

Use this editor to get the text being edited, or attach a document listener to it, or anything you like, as follows:

```
JTextComponent editor = (JTextEditor)component;

String text = editor.getText();

editor.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

    void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { ... }
    void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { ... }
    void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { ... }

});
```

Comment: can you tell me JTextEditor in this example? @eitanfar

Comment: It just return null pointer exception. because component contains null only. Can you tell clearly.

Comment: Well, it depends on your code. Usually, it would be a `JTextField` (since that's the component being initialized by `DefaultCellEditor` for text). However, you could set your own cell editor using one of `JTable`s methods: `setCellEditor(...), setDefaultEditor(...)` or override one of its methods: `getCellEditor(...), getDefaultEditor(...)`.

Comment: @Billu If you get `null` it means that no cell is currently being edited. Check out the JavaDoc for the method at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getCellEditor(int,%20int)

Comment: JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        
        
      table.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
 
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                
                    table.setCellEditor(null);
                    Component component = table.getEditorComponent();
                    JTextComponent editor = (JTextField)component;
                    System.out.println("Editor="+editor.getText());}}  Its my program. if i press sumthing in that table, i will show null pointer exception... Kindly check this code.

Comment: First of all, you code is not compiling. Secondly, the problem is that you're adding a `KeyListener` to the table, while the `KeyEvent`s go to the editor of the table. You'll only get `KeyEvent`s in the table either before or after the editing takes place, not during, at which time the editor is bound to be `null`.

Comment: i achieve it by placing a JTextField in Jtable and writing key listener for that textfield. its working fine. thanks for spending your time @eitanfar